# Finding A sub String and replacing the whole string in SQL

Tags: sql

Hi I'm wondering is there a way using sql to replace a string that contains a specific sub string with a new string on mass.
I can replace one string with another no problem(Find and Replace). However I have a situation where I need to replace thousands of lines where the strings are almost the same but not exactly. They all have a unique id appended to the end.I want to use the first part of the string which is the same for every line to identify the lines i want to change and replace the entire string with a new string which will not be unique across the table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Also please provide sample input and desired output

Answer (score 0):

The following works in most databases:

```
update t
    set col = newstring
    where left(col, xxx) = identifierstring;
```

I think this is what you are describing.